# Copying data from 2 sheets to single sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets of data with columns and rows.I want to add this data into third sheet.

Sheet 1 data:

```
id   sysid   option    status
XYZ  xyt        o      trade_1
US   xyt        c      trade_1
Ust  xt         o      trade_2
nj   xt         o      trade_2
CHN  zz         c      trade_3
rt   zz         o      trade_3
```

Sheet 2 data:

```
id  sysid   matched option  status
XYZ xyt     o   trade_1
US  xyt     c   trade_1
Ust xt      o   trade_2
nj  xt      o   trade_2
CHN zz      c   trade_3
rt  zz      o   trade_3
```

Output in sheet3 should be below:

```
id  sysid   option  status
XYZ xyt o   trade_1
US  xyt c   trade_1
CHN zz  c   trade_3
rt  zz  o   trade_3


id  sysid   matched option  status
XYZ xyt     o   trade_1
US  xyt     c   trade_1
CHN zz      c   trade_3
rt  zz      o   trade_3
```

Below code output the correct data,except after copying first sheet data,end of the next row sheet2 data will display

**Code i am trying:**

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    rowCount = 1
   Call Comparesheets("Sheet1", rowCount)
    rowCount = Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count
   Call Comparesheets("Sheet2", rowCount)

    End Sub

Sub Comparesheets(sheetname As String, rowa As Integer)

 Const COL_ID As Integer = 1
   Const COL_SYSID As Integer = 2
    Dim COL_STATUS As Integer
    Dim COL_OPTION As Integer
    Dim rowstr As String
    Dim sheet1 As Boolean
    Dim sheet2 As Boolean
    Const VAL_DIFF As String = "XXdifferentXX"
    If sheetname = "Sheet1" Then
    COL_STATUS = 4
    COL_OPTION = 3
    sheet1 = True
    sheet2 = False
    Else
    sheet2 = True
    sheet1 = False
    COL_STATUS = 5
    COL_OPTION = 4
    End If
    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim d As Object, sKey As String, id As String
    Dim rw As Range, opt As String, rngData As Range
    Dim rngCopy As Range, goodId As Boolean
    Dim FirstPass As Boolean, arr
    Set POSOpen = ActiveWorkbook
   rowNum = 1
        With Sheets(sheetname).Range("A1")
            Set rngData = .CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Resize( _
                             .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1)
        End With
      Set rngCopy = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)

        Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        FirstPass = True

redo:
        For Each rw In rngData.Rows

            sKey = rw.Cells(COL_SYSID).Value & "<>" & _
                   rw.Cells(COL_STATUS).Value

            If FirstPass Then
              'Figure out which combinations have different option values
              '  and at least one record with id=US or CHN
              id = rw.Cells(COL_ID).Value
              goodId = (id = "US" Or id = "CHN")
              opt = rw.Cells(COL_OPTION).Value

              If d.exists(sKey) Then
                  arr = d(sKey) 'can't modify the array in situ...
                  If arr(0) <> opt Then arr(0) = VAL_DIFF
                  If goodId Then arr(1) = True
                  d(sKey) = arr 'return [modified] array
              Else
                  d.Add sKey, Array(opt, goodId)
              End If

            Else
              'Second pass - copy only rows with varying options
              '  and id=US or CHN
              If d(sKey)(0) = VAL_DIFF And d(sKey)(1) = True Then
              If sheet1 Then
               Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Copy Sheet3.Cells(1, 1)
               rw.Copy rngCopy
              ' rowNum = rowNum + 1
              End If
              If sheet2 Then

              Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).Copy Sheet3.Cells(rowa + 1, 1)
              rw.Copy rngCopy

              End If

                  Set rngCopy = rngCopy.Offset(1, 0)
              End If
            End If

        Next rw
        If FirstPass Then

            FirstPass = False
            GoTo redo
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
Set rngCopy = Sheet3.Range("A1")
```

to this:

```
Set rngCopy = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).offset(2,0)
If rngCopy.Row=2 then Set rngCopy=Sheet3.Range("A1")
```

Comment: :Great work, I updated my code with your answer.It is good.But After first row,there blank row coming.I want output like,First set of columns and rows then blank row,then second set of data with columns and it's rows.if there is no data in first sheet1,then second sheet data start from row1.

Comment: I edited my answer, but you know you **could** have figured out the solution with a little effort.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the stipulations on how the data is going to change but something like this should work fairly quickly...

```
 Sub main()
 Dim MyStuff As Variant

 MyStuff = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a2:d6").Value

 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:d6") = MyStuff

 MyStuff = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("a2:d6").Value

 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a8:d12") = MyStuff

 End Sub
```

There are other methods that can be used fairly quickly. Like copy and paste for example, but the syntax of it's usage is annoying to me. I like simple and easy to remember and the above code is good for that.

Reading your code more it looks like you're looking for conditional copies, but the top section of your question looks like it's the same info. If I've misunderstood your request let me know and I'll try to adapt my code to your needs.

Comment: Hi,It wont work,because data is not limited.So i can't hard code the range.

Comment: not limited in both directions? You can always use Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address in the Range. Or if you know the last column used you can use .Range("C6000").end(xlup).row or .address or whatever. You can also use the .end method to go to the left or right. So you can make the range fit your range now matter how much it expands or contracts.